# How to set the same Date/Time for a Perl environment?

Tags: perl, debian-buster, centos-6.9

We have 2 environments: old (CentOS 6.9) and new (Debian 10).

Also we have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Time::ParseDate;
$seconds = parsedate('Jan 1, 1970');
print "$seconds\n";
```

It produces the following on old environment:

```
[user@old ~]$ ./test.pl
1577829600
```

And, It produces the following on new environment:

```
user@new:~$ ./test.pl
-10800
```

How do we fix this so that test.pl will output the same as on the old environment? Also please share some link(s) to read about this difference.

Comment: The old environment is quite clearly wrong, as that is the amount of seconds from the Unix epoch at Jan 1st, 2020 (in your time zone).

Comment: Shouldn't both systems return 0?  Since parsedate should return the number of seconds since the Unix epoch, which is Jan 1, 1970?   That's what I get on my system.

Comment: @Rob Sweet, Depends on whether `parsedate` accepts a local timestamp or not. If it expects a UTC timestamps, then yes, `parsedate('Jan 1, 1970')` should return `0`. But that's not necessarily the case. By default, `parsedate` accepts a timestamp in the time zone specified by the `TZ` env var. `parsedate('Jan 1, 1970')` should return `-5*60*60` for me in Toronto, since that represents `1970-01-01T00:00:00-05:00` aka `1969-12-31T19:00:00Z`. That is `5*60*60` seconds before the unix epoch, which is to say `-5*60*60` seconds past the unix epoch.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do `parsedate('Jan 1, 2020');` on the old system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1577829600` is the number of seconds between `2019-12-31T22:00:00Z` and the unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`).

If you're trying to get the number of seconds since the unix epoch, you can use the builtin [`time`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html).

```
$ perl -e'CORE::say time'
1580776856
```

On the other hand, if you're trying to get the epoch time for Jan 1st of the current year of your local time zone, you can use `parsedate('Jan 1')`.